# Reference Fiscal Quarter (Current FQ /Previous FQ) in Formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, activity-settings

I have a custom formula field on Accounts called 'Has Activities this Quarter' which I would like to display 'Yes' if there is activities created against the account in this current fiscal quarter, or 'No' if there are no activities created in this current fiscal quarter.

So far I have used the below which works for the past 90 days, but does not take quarters into consideration:

```
IF( LastActivityDate > TODAY() - 90, "Yes", "No")
```

Any ideas how we can bring Fiscal Quarters into Formula Fields?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am calculating a revenue schedule 1 to 8 quarters out from a close date. I needed to calculate the Fiscal Quarter for each quarter beyound the Close Date and Display the Revenue Quarter as:
"Qx-20xx" or Q3-2011.

Here is my formula for Revenue Quarter x (Rev_Qtr_x__C)=

```
CASE(MONTH(Revenue_Start_Date__c+(x*DiQ__c )),1,"Q1",2,"Q1",3,"Q1",4,"Q2",5,"Q2",6,"Q2",7,"Q3",8,"Q3",9,"Q3",10,"Q4",11,"Q4",12,"Q4","None") &"-"&TEXT(YEAR(Revenue_Start_Date__c +(x* DiQ__c )))
```

where DiQ = day in a quarter=91.25
Revenue Start Date__c = date revenu starts (Comes from a calculation on the close date)
x= Revenue quarter beyound start date.

The key was to keep the formula as a TEXT and cantonate the display values.